# Xamarin Forms MvvmCross and Xamarin iOS/Android co-existing

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, migration, mvvmcross

I have an app written using Xamarin iOS and Android and it uses MvvmCross.

I would like to gradually migrate it to Xamarin Forms. So this would mean new views/controls would be Xamarin Forms, but existing views/Controls would be migrated over time as and when they need to change.

Is it possible for Xamarin Forms, iOS, Android and MvvmCross to co-exist int he same application?

If anyone has done this could you let me know how you went about this, and any problems issues you have come up against.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a project someone is working on that will allow you to navigate to Xamarin Forms Pages as easily as you do Mvx Views.

<strike>https://github.com/munkii/MvxAndXamForms</strike>

The project has moved to a Fork of MVVMCross 5.0 here, https://github.com/munkii/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Forms/NativeToXF

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this looks promising. So I am now assuming there is nothing within the MvvmCross framework to allow this.  I rely on MvvmCross for things like state restore etc. My worry if that I will get a steady stream of issues if I try to roll my own implementation.